# Using appcompat previous versions on already installed sdk 21 version

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have updated my SDK version using the update to version 21. This new release is coming with a new appcompat the is not allowing previous features from the ActionBar like the icon in the top, requiring to introduce the new concept of toolbar.

So, I prefer the previous implemented behaviour, and changing my app to adapt to this new concept requires some time. I would like to keep the previous version of the library, however, my SDK is already updated.

Is there any way to cancel the update of the appcompat and use previous versions? Or compiling appcompat with compatibility with previous versions?

Comment: I would suggest that you take the time to upgrade your app to use the new Appcompat. Without that, you will not be able to take advantage of new Android features (like Material design themes, etc) and provide them on devices with older Android versions. Also if somehow you are able to use old Appcompats, it is not advisable to use deprecated code.

Comment: I agree.... but not know. Right now is not the moment. I want to control my app development strategy not be controlled by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the previous support library while using the current sdk, platform and build tools and sdk. It will always ask for the Material design files for example. Go to the SDK manager and remove the packages for sdk 21, all of them and download the API 19, which is Kitkat and not Wearables sdk.

Comment: I already tried. The problem is that the version of the appcompat will keep the same and will give problems of missing dependences.

Comment: It is not true.You can use the api 21 with the support library 19.

Comment: are you using Gradle? If so you can use there: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'

Comment: I am using eclipse. What I did was to download sdk19 (and keeping sdk21) and configuring all projects (my app and the library) to be compiled in 19. Is it needed to remove the sdk21? If so, why is making the difference?

Comment: it is just because you are not going to use it at all. So why keep it? Do as you like, but you need the previous support appcompat and compile with sdk 19 including using previous versions of build tools and platform. If you cannot find the previous support library you will have to compile with sdk 21

Comment: What is happening is the following. When I try to download a new ADT version and I only download sdk19 the version installed of appcompat includes Material resources, so the library in eclipse provides errors and I can't compile the application.  The only option I have is having SDK21 and compiling appcompat with it to avoid errors. Problem is that I can't only download the latest package... and includes values-21 and Material.